# Проверка на столкновение сложных фигур (Android)

Tags: java, android

К примеру, есть изображение 2D-объекта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как проверить столкновение другого объекта, например пули, с краями этой фигуры? Я имею ввиду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. **НЕ** с границами изображения.
2. А с границами самой фигуры.

Буду рад любым статьям или примерам. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен алгоритм определяющий *точка находится внутри полигона или снаружи?*

Обычно проверка делается в 2 приема:

1. Проверка на границу изображения (это быстро)
2. Если точка находится внутри границ изображения - то трассировка лучей, если луч пересекает границу четное количество раз - то точка за полигоном, если нечетное, то снаружи - это не очень быстро.

Поищите статьи на тему *ray casting algorithm*, например можно [почитать эту](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm#Java)

Comment: Спасибо, уже нашел несколько статей по трассировке лучей, очень похоже на то, чего я хочу достичь. [Вот](https://habr.com/post/124869/)  на хабре наткнулся  и [тут](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe30.htm) статейка. Осталось подробнее разобраться. Спасибо.